# Why are there two hashes in my Pipfile.lock for one module?

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile

I've started using pipenv and installed the flask package.

In my Pipfile.lock there is this entry:

```
 "flask": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:2271c0070dbcb5275fad4a82e29f23ab92682dc45f9dfbc22c02ba9b9322ce48",
                "sha256:a080b744b7e345ccfcbc77954861cb05b3c63786e93f2b3875e0913d44b43f05"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==1.0.2"
        },
```

I wonder why there are two different hashes. Can anyone elaborate on this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just take a look at https://pypi.org/project/Flask/1.0.2/#files

2271c0070dbcb5275fad4a82e29f23ab92682dc45f9dfbc22c02ba9b9322ce48 is the tar.gz a080b744b7e345ccfcbc77954861cb05b3c63786e93f2b3875e0913d44b43f05 is the wheel-file